# Jinja/WTForms: Displaying a single radio button

Tags: python, flask, iterator, jinja2, wtforms

How does one display a single radio button (out of a group) from a WTForms form in Jinja?

Basically, I want to have a form on a webpage that looks like:

> o Radio option1
>
> > ```
> > Various sub-options here
> > ```
>
> o Radio option2
>
> > ```
> > Some more sub-options, totally different from the first group
> > ```
>
> o Radio option3
>
> > ```
> > Yet more sub-options (again, different)
> > ```
>
> [Submit button]

...and then toggle the rendering of the sub-groups at run-time via Javascript (this part I have taken care of).

So. I have the radio buttons defined as a single `RadioField` in WTForms:

```python
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    radio_opts = RadioField(
        "Caption",
        choices=[('1', "Radio option1"), ('2', "Radio option2"), ('3', "Radio option3")]
    )
    ...
```

But because of the sub-options, I don't want to just display the whole field at once, and because the sub-options are totally different, it doesn't make sense to loop through the options à la

```html
{% for option in form.radio_opts %}
    <div>{{ option }} {{ option.label }}</div>
    <div>{# now figuring out what goes in here becomes rather awkward... #}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It seems to me the ideal way would be to just be able to

```html
<div>{{ form.radio_opts[0] }} {{ form.radio_opts[0].label }}</div>
<div>{# first set of sub-options #}</div>
<div>{{ form.radio_opts[1] }} {{ form.radio_opts[1].label }}</div>
<div>{# second set of sub-options #}</div>
<div>{{ form.radio_opts[2] }} {{ form.radio_opts[2].label }}</div>
<div>{# third set of sub-options #}</div>
```

But subscripting `form.radio_opts` like that gives the error `...RadioField object has no element 0`

Ok, so? I've tried casting to a list/tuple, I've tried using `next()` -- Jinja won't have any of it.

Thoughts on alternate ways to get a form like the above are also welcome!

**Update**

So this is how I ended up solving it. I don't like it at all - there has *got* to be a better way. But this does the trick for now...

```
{% set opts = namespace(opt1=None, opt2=None, opt3=None) %}
{% for option in form.radio_opts %}
    {% if loop.index == 1 %}
        {% set opts.opt1 = option %}
    {% elif loop.index == 2 %}
        {% set opts.opt2 = option %}
    {% elif loop.index == 3 %}
        {% set opts.opt3 = option %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a single radio button you can use BooleanField in your form :

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):

   option1 = BooleanField(u'label', ...)
```

And in your template :

```
{{ form.option1 }}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was hoping more for something that would still allow me to use the same wtforms field for all the buttons in the group (so they'd  have the same name and auto unselect the others when one was selected, etc.), but still give me finer-grained control over the rendering. But appreciate the response!